# How to do pixel art in processing via scaling

Tags: graphics, processing, scale

I'd rather not recreate every draw function to use rectangles, as this seems unnecessary. I may end up using more complex draw functions like `arc()` and porting it to use rectangles seems like a waste of time.

Using `scale()` works ok, but it renders the result of the `point()` function as a circle. I tried putting `noSmooth()` in the `setup()` but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Ideally I'd like to have a grid of 64 X 48 pixels rendered at 640 X 480 so that each pixel is ten times as large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't have to use `rect()` for functions like `arc()`. You'd just use `rect()` instead of `point()`.

But if it really bothers you that much, consider this approach:

- Draw everything to a 64x48 `PGraphics` buffer using the standard scale. This would allow you to use the `point()` function.
- Then scale that `PGraphics` instance using the `scale()` or `image()` functions to draw it to the screen.

More info is available in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html).

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work out with `PGraphics`, could I get a code sample?

Comment: @FracturedRetina There is a code sample in the link to the reference I gave you. If you still can't get it working, please post what you've tried as a [mcve], and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake when I took a closer look. Thanks for your help.